# Why my perl one-liner has different output for same command

Tags: perl

I am trying to run perl one liner to get the string from a header file "elf.h" which has following lines :-

```
#define ELFOSABIV_STDELF_V1          8U      // STD ELF ABI
#define ELFOSABIV_PRE_STDELF         7U      // latest abi version
#define ELFOSABIV_LATEST             6U      // latest abi version
```

I am trying to get `ELFOSABIV_LATEST` version which is `6U`. Actually i need to feed this output to executable file. So i have to go with perl one liner to make it simple.

Output :-

In Linux:-

```
perl -ne "print $1 if /#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\S+)/" /home/test/elf/elf.h
#define ELFOSABIV_LATEST             6U   // latest abi version
```

In Windows:-

```
perl -ne "print $1 if /#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\S+)/" /home/test/elf/elf.h
 6U
```

Why is the difference in output among windows and linux above? Do i need to set something before printing. I need to make sure that output has to be `6U` for both windows and linux.

Answer (score 3):

In a Linux shell, a dollar sign `$` inside double quotes gets interpreted as a variable. Since `$1` is undefined, it gets translated into an empty string, so the double-quoted argument effectively becomes:

```
print  if /#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\S+)/
```

when passed to perl, resulting in the entire line being printed when the `if` condition is evaluated as true.

You can remedy it by enclosing the one-liner in single quotes instead to prevent dollar signs from being interpreted by shell:

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\S+)/' /home/test/elf/elf.h
```

Note that in Windows you do have to quote arguments with double qoutes, so if you want to maintain just one version of the script you would be better off writing an actual script instead of a one-liner command:

```
# filter.pl
while (<>) {
    print $1 if /#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\S+)/;
}
```

so that:

```
perl filter.pl /home/test/elf/elf.h
```

would output `6U` in both platforms.

On the other hand, for your particular use case, you can rewrite your perl code so that it doesn't use any `$` to reference variables, allowing you to use double quotes to enclose the argument on both platforms:

```
perl -ne "print /#define\s+ELFOSABIV_LATEST\s+(\S+)/" /home/test/elf/elf.h
```

But again, referencing a variable with a `$` is sometimes unavoidable, in which case you should write it as a separate script to be portable.

Comment: Yeah..but in windows having single quotes would not work. it throws the error :- `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.`

Comment: Windows is not designed to be Linux/*NIX. You have to either live with using two different one-liners for two different platforms, or make the one-liner an actual perl script for perl to run without shell interpretation. Updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a one-liner that does solve your particular use case on both platforms.

Comment: Why not use `<>` instead of `<STDIN>` so the program is not hardcoded to use stdin only.